# JavaScript: How to make outputs replace previous outputted entry when buttons are pressed more than once

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been tasked with creating a pizza menu for my schools final JavaScript project. I have finished everything aside from a problem I'm having with the order button.

When clicked, the order button compiles a list of the added items (along with their values) and prints them to the front end for the user to see. Whenever the button is clicked again, a new output is created and 'stacked' underneath the original entry. This can go on and on, depending on how many times the button is re-clicked.

My question, is there a way to have any new clicks on my button replace the visual output, instead of adding to the 'receipt'? I hope I'm being clear.

https://github.com/yugenaugur/Tech-Academy-Pizza-Menu-Project

Stacking results below the previous outputs, instead of replacing the value on the screen - altogether.

Thanks a lot for any and all help, this one has been driving me nuts.

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue comes down to the use of append. What you are telling it do is is to add to the end every time instead of replace.

You can do this 2 ways, either concat everything into a string and replace the value, or clear the value first, then append.

Concat

```
var item_html = '';
for (key in receipt) {
   var item = '<th class="item">' + key + '</th>'
   var price = '<th class="item">' + receipt[key] + '</th>'
   item_html = item_html + '<tr>' + item + price + '</tr>';
}
item_html = item_html + '<tr><th class="total">Total:</th><th class="total">' + total + '</th></tr>';
$('.table').find('tbody:last').html(item_html);
```

Clear First (place before loop)

```
$('.table').find('tbody:last').html('');
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: You need to get an element, and overwrite the content on each click. Not append.

```js
let items = ['pizza', 'bread', 'coke'];

const getLineItem = (item) => `<p>${item}</p>`;

document.querySelector('.summary').addEventListener('click', function() {
    let target = document.querySelector('.receipt');
    let lines = '';
    items.forEach(item => {
      lines += getLineItem(item);
    });
    target.innerHTML = lines;
});
```

```html
<div class="receipt"></div>
<button class="summary">Summary</button>
```